# Knockout: how to bind non-DOM properties (options of some DOM elements)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, devextreme

Context: I am using a MVC extensions library that generates some controls and I would like to bind some inner properties of two generated controls.

For example:
a grid defined by `#dataGrid` with the inner property located in its sub-sub-property `_options.selection.mode` and a selection box defined by `#selectBox` and its property `value`.

How can I achieve that?

[EDIT]
I am using the ones from DevExtreme
From I am seeing the generation is not that, a simple example:

Here is ASP.NET View below:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().SelectBox()
                  .ID("selectionMode")
                  .Placeholder("Select...")
                  .DataSource(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SelectionMode)))
                  .SearchEnabled(true)
                  .SearchMode(DropDownSearchMode.StartsWith))
```

And here is the related code generated:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#selectionMode").dxSelectBox({
        "placeholder":"Select...",
        "dataSource":{"store":new DevExpress.data.ArrayStore({"data":["multiple","none","single"]})},
        "searchEnabled":true,"searchMode":"startswith"});
    });
</script>
```

I can access the instance via jQuery: `$("#selectionMode").dxSelectBox("instance")`

Also, it seems that for some reasons value is also stored in the "options" (js-wise):

```
$("#selectionMode").dxSelectBox("instance")._options.value
```

So basically if there is another say component generated with the same fashion where the property mode would be available:

```
$("#dataGrid").dxDataGrid("instance")._options.selection.mode
```

I would like that those two (`mode` and `values`) to be bound to each other, I'm sure it's dead simple (but I'm still pretty new to knockout).

Comment: Not sure how they are being generated, but you could try using a custom binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that gets hold of these properties, creating computeds which you can watch.  Something like what rniemeyer talks about with jquery-datapicker here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

Comment: Please share all the relevant code. How are you using the extensions, what is the generated code, what exactly you expect etc

Comment: @adiga done, let me know if there is anything else you would like to know about my issue.

Comment: @Timh thanks, it looks like the case mentioned in 5- Two-way binding that needs to broker getting/setting data with a 3rd party control